# Vector push_back and destructor function(?): push_back(~Dword(0))

Tags: c++, vector, std, destructor

Here is the code:

```
std::vector<Dword> s;

s.push_back(~Dword(0));
```

What is `~Dword`? How does it work?

Comment: It appears to just be a type. Have you googled it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dword` here is a numeric type (probably a type alias for `DWORD`; an unsigned 32 bit integer). When you write `Dword(0)`, you make a `Dword` with the value `0`, then `~Dword(0)` does a bitwise negation of it.

So `~Dword(0)` is read as *bitwise-negate* a *Dword* of value *0*

Comment: To add: Which is 0xffffffff